# Stash - a variable that was set is not showing the correct value

Tags: stash, parse-order

I have this code, setting some information to stash variables

```
{exp:rest parse="inward" ...}
    <h2>foo_1 in exp:rest = {foo}</h2>
    <h2>bar_1 in exp:rest = {bar}</h2>
    {exp:stash:set name="foo_1"}{foo}{/exp:stash:set}
    {exp:stash:set name="bar_1"}{bar}{/exp:stash:set}
{/exp:rest}

{exp:rest parse="inward" ...}
    <h2>foo_2 in exp:rest = {foo}</h2>
    <h2>bar_2 in exp:rest = {bar}</h2>
    {exp:stash:set name="foo_2"}{foo}{/exp:stash:set}
    {exp:stash:set name="bar_2_2"}{bar}{/exp:stash:set}
{/exp:rest}
```

The code above outputs

```
foo_1 in exp:rest = -35.2286
bar_1 in exp:rest = 173.9478
foo_2 in exp:rest = 0
bar_2 in exp:rest = 0
```

...but retrieving them returns nothing. The code below

```
<h1>foo_1="{exp:stash:foo_1}"</h1>
<h1>bar_1="{exp:stash:bar_1}"</h1>
<h1>foo_2="{exp:stash:foo_2}"</h1>
<h1>bar_2="{exp:stash:bar_2}"</h1>
```

outputs

```
foo_1=""
bar_1=""
foo_2=""
bar_2=""
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a parse order issue, your setting stash inside outer tags then trying to retrieve outside the order, i'd probably do this:

```
{exp:stash:set parse_tags="yes"}
{stash:results}
{exp:rest ...}
    <h2>foo_1 in exp:rest = {foo}</h2>
    <h2>bar_1 in exp:rest = {bar}</h2>
    {stash:foo_1}{foo}{/stash:foo_1}
    {stash:bar_1}{bar}{/stash:bar_1}
{/exp:rest}

{exp:rest ...}
    <h2>foo_2 in exp:rest = {foo}</h2>
    <h2>bar_2 in exp:rest = {bar}</h2>
    {stash:foo_2}{foo}{/stash:foo_2}
    {stash:bar_2}{bar}{/stash:bar_2}
{/exp:rest}
{/stash:results}
{/exp:stash:set}
```

Then grab the vars like:

```
{exp:stash:get name="results"}
  <h1>foo_1="{stash:foo_1}"</h1>
  <h1>bar_1="{stash:bar_1}"</h1>
  <h1>foo_2="{stash:foo_2}"</h1>
  <h1>bar_2="{stash:bar_2}"</h1>
{/exp:stash:get}
```

OR simply this may work too (add parse to the get function):

```
{exp:rest parse="inward" ...}
    <h2>foo_1 in exp:rest = {foo}</h2>
    <h2>bar_1 in exp:rest = {bar}</h2>
    {exp:stash:set name="foo_1"}{foo}{/exp:stash:set}
    {exp:stash:set name="bar_1"}{bar}{/exp:stash:set}
{/exp:rest}

{exp:rest parse="inward" ...}
    <h2>foo_2 in exp:rest = {foo}</h2>
    <h2>bar_2 in exp:rest = {bar}</h2>
    {exp:stash:set name="foo_2"}{foo}{/exp:stash:set}
    {exp:stash:set name="bar_2_2"}{bar}{/exp:stash:set}
{/exp:rest}

{exp:stash:parse process="end"}
  <h1>foo_1="{exp:stash:foo_1}"</h1>
  <h1>bar_1="{exp:stash:bar_1}"</h1>
  <h1>foo_2="{exp:stash:foo_2}"</h1>
  <h1>bar_2="{exp:stash:bar_2}"</h1>
{/exp:stash:parse}
```